# Access to a dynamically created element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid, pseudo-element

I need to access a dynamically created element with jQuery. My html code is as follows:

```
<div class="row" id="divRowBtnAdd">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5" id="divBtnAddRow">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="btnAddRow">
        Click for another radius and diameter line
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The element is created using the jQuery .before() function:

```
$("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
$("#divRowBtnAdd").before('<div class="row" id="radiusDiameter">' +
'<div class="form-group col-md-2">' +
'    <label for="radius">Radius</label>' +
'    <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.1" id="radius" placeholder="Radius">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="form-group col-md-2">' +
'    <label for="diameter">Diameter</label>' +
'    <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.1" id="diameter" placeholder="Diameter">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="form-group col-md-4">' +
'    <br/> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete line" id="btnCloseDivCurva"/>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>')
});
```

The elements are created successfully, but when I run:

```
var count = $("#radiusDiameter").length;
```

the value returned is always 1, not the value of elements created +1 ...

Comment: You need to hoist the scope and make use of event delegation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one element with the same `id`.  Instead, append it with a class of `radiusDiameter` and then use a selector like this.

```
var count = $(".radiusDiameter").length;
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much! I had notion of not being able to use the same id, but didn't know that when using the value in the class the result would be expected, thank you!